# How to add "continued from previous page" hint to page breaking **mdframed**?

Tags: mdframed

Follow-up question to the accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132769/27721) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42632/27721). The latter seems promising, with the caveat that it doesn't work.

- I'm using **`mdframed`** with **`tikz`** - but without "theorems". However, I too would like to see the title upon page breaks with a "continued" hint. How?

**Screenshot**, followed by **MWE**:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}

% \usepackage[heightrounded=true, textheight=735pt, textwidth=430pt, layoutvoffset=27pt, hcentering, includefoot, headheight=26pt, headsep=10pt, footskip=10pt, showframe]{geometry}


\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

% \mdfsetup{skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=1\topskip, nobreak=true, innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip, frametitleaboveskip=2pt, frametitlebelowskip=1pt}
%%%

\mdfdefinestyle{my_style_testing}{frametitlebackgroundcolor=pink}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\vspace{5cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{mdframed}[style=my_style_testing,frametitle=\color{blue}{What an interesting title this is...}]

hello world

\lipsum[1]

\vspace{5cm}

\lipsum[3]

\vspace{5cm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{mdframed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want just the text for the title or the text *with* the formatting (background color, etc)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The whole thing again (pink frame and all) *plus* "continued..."

Comment: At first glance, [this looks almost like an answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42632/27721) to me.

Comment: If it's a short document, a **"manual"** solution, i.e. "faking it": just another box/frame with *`continued`* in title, will do the trick. For longer documents the **"automatic"** solution would be desirable, though.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95988/5049

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Possibly you'll need some minor adjustments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

% \mdfsetup{skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=1\topskip, nobreak=true, innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip, frametitleaboveskip=2pt, frametitlebelowskip=1pt}
%%%

\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{my_style_testing}{
  frametitlebackgroundcolor=pink,
  splittopskip=3\baselineskip,
  middleextra={
    \node[
      text width=\the\dimexpr\linewidth-2\mdf@outerlinewidth@length-%
         2\mdf@middlelinewidth@length-2\mdf@innerlinewidth@length-%
         2\mdf@innerleftmargin@length\relax,
      anchor=north west,
      font=\mdf@frametitlefont,
      inner xsep=\mdf@innerleftmargin@length,
      outer sep=0pt,
      mdfframetitlebackground,
      rounded corners={max(\mdf@roundcorner@length%
                                         -\mdf@innerlinewidth@length%
                                        -.5\mdf@middlelinewidth@length,0)%
                                    }%
    ] at (P-|O) {\mdf@frametitle\ (Continued)};
  },
  secondextra={
    \node[
      text width=\the\dimexpr\linewidth-2\mdf@outerlinewidth@length-%
         2\mdf@middlelinewidth@length-2\mdf@innerlinewidth@length-%
         2\mdf@innerleftmargin@length\relax,
      anchor=north west,
      font=\mdf@frametitlefont,
      inner xsep=\mdf@innerleftmargin@length,
      outer sep=0pt,
      mdfframetitlebackground,
      rounded corners={max(\mdf@roundcorner@length%
                                         -\mdf@innerlinewidth@length%
                                        -.5\mdf@middlelinewidth@length,0)%
                                    }%
    ] at (P-|O) 
    {%
      \vbox{%
        \parskip\z@\relax%
        \parindent\z@\relax%
        \vskip\mdf@frametitleaboveskip@length%
        \mdf@frametitle\ (Continued)%
        \mdf@@frametitlerule\relax%
        \unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one\relax%
      }%
    };
  }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\vspace{5cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{mdframed}[style=my_style_testing,frametitle=\color{blue}{What an interesting title this is...}]

hello world

\lipsum[1]

\vspace{5cm}

\lipsum[3]

\vspace{5cm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{mdframed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I still need help regarding the "minor adjustments": the second ("continued") title is significantly thicker than the original one. I'd like them to be exactly the same. How?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a short document, a **"manual"** solution, i.e. "faking it": just another box/frame with *`continued`* in title, will do the trick. For longer documents the **"automatic"** solution would be desirable, though.