# mdframed: how to design "exercise" box

Tags: mdframed

For theorems and a like I use `mdframed` package. For theorems, definitions I use standard design, meanwhile for examples and exercises I rather to have more exotic one ...

So far I succeed to make the following solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    node distance= 0mm and 3mm,
ws/.style={align=#1,
           font=\large\bfseries\sffamily, 
           draw, thin, fill=white,
           overlay,
           }
        }

\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{example}%
{%
    hidealllines=true, 
    skipabove=2\baselineskip, skipbelow=-1ex,
    innertopmargin=0pt, innerbottommargin=0pt,%
    middlelinewidth=5pt, linecolor=red,%
    fontcolor=teal, font=\small\sffamily,%
%
settings={%\global\refstepcounter{example}
        \ifodd\value{page}
    \boolfalse{mdf@leftline}
    \booltrue{mdf@rightline}
        \else
    \booltrue{mdf@leftline}
    \boolfalse{mdf@rightline}
        \fi},
    innerrightmargin=\ifodd\value{page}0.5em\else 0.0em\fi, %rightmargin=7em,%
    innerleftmargin =\ifodd\value{page}0.0em\else 0.5em\fi, %leftmargin =7em,%
singleextra={
        \ifodd\value{page}
\node[ws=left,below right=of P] {\theexample};
        \else
\node[ws=right,below left=of O |- P]  {\theexample};
        \fi
             },%
}% end of mdfdefinestyle
\makeatother

\mdtheorem[style=example,
           ]{example}{Example}[chapter]

\mdtheorem[style=exercise,
           ]{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
    This is produced by \verb+\begin{mdframed}[style=example] ... \end{mdframed}+
\end{mdframed}
xxxxxxxxx 
\begin{example}
    This is produced by \verb+\begin{example} ... \end{example}+
\end{example}

\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I like to have the "Example " instead of top of an example tex rather in the box with now with number on the right side of text (or on the left side, if page is even). Is this possible?

Any improvement of my code is also welcome!

**Addendum:**
Meanwhile I gave-up to manage solution with `mdframed` and define equivalent environments with `tcolorbox` (as suggested in early comments). With it the solution is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{showframe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  EXERCISES                                                   %
%%==============================================================%
\newcounter{task}
\AtBeginEnvironment{task}{\linespread{.9}\selectfont}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\newtcolorbox[use counter=task,
              number within=section,
              ]{task}%
   {enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable,
    toggle left and right,
    boxrule=0mm,
    colback=white, colframe=red,
    top=0mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
    arc=0mm,
    borderline={0.5pt}{0pt}{red, sharp corners},
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily, fontlower=\normalsize\sffamily,
    rightrule=1mm,
overlay={\renewcommand\thetcbcounter{\thesection-\arabic{\tcbcounter}}%
\tcbifoddpage{\node[font=\large\sffamily, text=red, inner sep=0mm,
                    below right=0mm and \marginparsep] at (frame.north east) {Vaja
                    \thetcbcounter};}
             {\node[font=\large\sffamily, text=red, inner sep=0mm,
                    below left=0mm and \marginparsep]  at (frame.north west) {Vaja
                    \thetcbcounter};}
        }%end of overlay
    }% end of task

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Test of "task" environment defined\newline 
         with use of "tcolorbox" package}
I looking for equivalent solution with package \verb+mdframed+, so far my attempts was unsuccessful.
\begin{task}
    This is produced by \verb+\begin{task}{}{} ... \end{task}+ defined with \verb+tcolorbox+
\end{task}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{task}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{task}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Result is almost satisfactory ... in it I miss identification if the "Vaja ..." is on the second page or not. if it is, I like to add (in second line) "nadaljevanje" (continue), but this I left for time when I will finished text book, where I use this environment.

Now I testing of G. Bay solution. As is, it works, unfortunately without numbering, as I expected, however, with its integration in my collection `mdframed` based theorems, definitions etc, I still have problems.

In final solution I like to obtain similar solution of use as is used in other `mdframed` theorems, for example at definition:

```
    \begin{definition}{Informacija}{info}
    \index{informacije!definicija}
Informacija je enaka nezanesljivosti, ki jo nastop dogodka odstrani.
    \end{definition}
Iz definicije \ref{def:info} sledi:
```

So I sill looking for any suggestion.

Comment: Could you accept `tcolorbox` alternatives?

Comment: If I will not be able to manage `mdframed` solution, I will accept `tcolorbox` alternative :-). In this case I need to rewrote existing solution for other `mdframed` boxes that I unified design of my documents. It seems, that `mdframed` is death-end way :-(

Comment: Could you explain a little better what exactly do you need? Or give a printscreen/photo edited of the desired result.

Comment: Oh, meanwhile I left `mdframed` and now use `tcolorbox` for my needs ... however, I will try to elaborate question (in late evening)  again. Shortly: how to build framed boxes which is aware for being on odd or even page even their part broken if box lay on two pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is more or less what you had in mind:

[image: Example title at even/odd pages]

Basically what did was add the following:

```
frametitle={\ifodd\value{page} \rlap{\hspace*{15pt} Example}  \else \llap{Example \hspace*{15pt}}\fi},, %This is used to overright the numbering rightafter the "Example" in the original frame title (which was above the text)
frametitlealignment={\ifodd\value{page} \raggedleft \else \raggedright\fi},
```

- The word "Example" is not directly above the title as before, it's
  now beside.
- There is no numbering on it.
- The word "Example" does change from left/right on
  odd/even pages.
- The word "Example" gets correctly positioned even
  when the mdframed spread across pagebreak.

Note how the `example` environment still uses the frametitle with numbering above the text, unlike the `style=example`.
Additional tuning might be required to change text color/font or box it, etc.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    node distance= 0mm and 3mm,
ws/.style={align=#1,
           font=\large\bfseries\sffamily, 
           draw, thin, fill=white,
           overlay,
           }
        }

\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{example}%
{%
    hidealllines=true, 
    skipabove=2\baselineskip, skipbelow=-1ex,
    innertopmargin=0pt, innerbottommargin=0pt,%
    middlelinewidth=5pt, linecolor=red,%
    fontcolor=teal, font=\small\sffamily,%
    frametitle={\ifodd\value{page} \rlap{\hspace*{15pt} Example}  \else \llap{Example \hspace*{15pt}}\fi},, %This is used to overright the numbering rightafter the "Example" in the original frame title (which was above the text)
    frametitlealignment={\ifodd\value{page} \raggedleft \else \raggedright\fi},
%
%
settings={%\global\refstepcounter{example}
        \ifodd\value{page}
    \boolfalse{mdf@leftline}
    \booltrue{mdf@rightline}
        \else
    \booltrue{mdf@leftline}
    \boolfalse{mdf@rightline}
        \fi},
    innerrightmargin=\ifodd\value{page}0.5em\else 0.0em\fi, %rightmargin=7em,%
    innerleftmargin =\ifodd\value{page}0.0em\else 0.5em\fi, %leftmargin =7em,%
singleextra={
%        \ifodd\value{page}
%\node[ws=left,below right=of P] {Example}; %These were the numbers beside them
%        \else
%\node[ws=right,below left=of O |- P]  {Example};
%        \fi
             },%
}% end of mdfdefinestyle
\makeatother

\mdtheorem[style=example,
           ]{example}{Example}[chapter]

\mdtheorem[style=exercise,
           ]{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
    This is produced by \verb+\begin{mdframed}[style=example] ... \end{mdframed}+
\end{mdframed}
xxxxxxxxx 
\begin{example}
    This is produced by \verb+\begin{example} ... \end{example}+
\end{example}

\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
        \lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: After some details added I modified the code to meet:

- Numbering after word "example"
- Left/right according to even/odd page.
- A "continue" text when the frame splits over another page.

To do that I used the `firstextra` (add "Exemple numbering" to all frames) and the `secondextra` (add "continue" only to first part of splited frames). Read more at secion 7 `Hooks and Bools` of `mdframed` manual.
And if you wish to add a "continued from" in the last part of the splited frame check [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185811/how-to-add-continued-from-previous-page-hint-to-page-breaking-mdframed).

[image: continue on the next page...]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    node distance= 0mm and 3mm,
ws/.style={align=#1,
           font=\large\bfseries\sffamily, 
           draw, thin, fill=white,
           overlay,
           }
        }
%\newcounter{example} maybe this is unnecessary
\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{example}%
{%
    hidealllines=true,    
    skipabove=2\baselineskip, skipbelow=-1ex,
    innertopmargin=0pt, innerbottommargin=0pt,%
    middlelinewidth=5pt, linecolor=red,%
    fontcolor=teal, font=\small\sffamily,%
%
settings={\global\refstepcounter{example} %this was commented, it is now active
        \ifodd\value{page}
    \boolfalse{mdf@leftline}
    \booltrue{mdf@rightline}
        \else
    \booltrue{mdf@leftline}
    \boolfalse{mdf@rightline}
        \fi},
    innerrightmargin=\ifodd\value{page}0.5em\else 0.0em\fi, %rightmargin=7em,%
    innerleftmargin =\ifodd\value{page}0.0em\else 0.5em\fi, %leftmargin =7em,%
    %
singleextra={
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \node[ws=left,draw=none,below right=of P] { Example \theexample };
            \else
    \node[ws=right,draw=none,below left=of O |- P]  {Example \theexample };
            \fi
                 },%
firstextra={
\ifodd\value{page}
\node[ws=left,draw=none,below right=of P] { Example \theexample };
\node[ws=left,yshift=-2em,below right=of P] { continue \ldots };
        \else
\node[ws=right,draw=none,below left=of O |- P]  {Example \theexample };
\node[ws=right,draw=none,yshift=-2em,below left=of O |- P]  {continue \ldots };
        \fi
             },%
}% end of mdfdefinestyle
\makeatother

\mdtheorem[style=example,
           ]{example}{Example}[chapter]

\mdtheorem[style=exercise,
           ]{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
    This is produced by \verb+\begin{mdframed}[style=example] \end{mdframed}+
\end{mdframed}
xxxxxxxxx 
\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
    This is produced by \verb+\begin{mdframed}[style=example] \end{mdframed}+
\end{mdframed}
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
        \lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that this is solution. Since I'm on the way, I will test this at end of week.

Comment: I've actually look at tcolorbox because of  Ignasi comment and sicne you seem to have adopted. It is indeed better and I will convert my doc. Hope this is still useful.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say `tcolorbox` is *better*. Better for what? I think `mdframed` is much more straightforward to use, especially for boxes which automatically break across pages. `tcolorbox` is all the bells and whistles. But sometimes you don't need the bells or want the whistles and all that cacophony just gives you a headache! @Zarko Do you mean you are away at the moment?

Comment: @cfr, yes, I'm on one conference in Bratislava. I have time to look TeX.SE only  early in the morning or late evening  :-)  and I haven't my test files with `mdframed` and ˙`tcolorbox` on my laptop. On the first sight it seems very promising (+1). Regardless that I temporary solve my problem with `tcolorbox`, I still have some older files with `mdframed`, to which I like to add some new examples and to stresses.

Comment: @G.Bay, I still testing your solution. Just now I add addendum to my question in which I show temporary solution with `tcolorbox` and described what I miis in it and example of expected use of solution with `mdframed`. Now I trying to include your solution into `mdframed` theorems, however temporary I'm focused in textbook contents and left forms to sparse time :-(. If in resonabletime I will not be able to include your solution into other `mdframed` theorems, I will ask new question and before (odf course) accept yours.

Comment: I agree with you cfr , tcolorbox is better for some things, usually fancy things, lol. Indeed mdframed can be simple to code thought the amount of code looks bigger.
@Zarko see my edited answer, hope it gets what you need.

Comment: @G.Bay, your edit is enough close to what I like to have for accepting your answer. If I will stuck with planed further adoption/modification for form unified design of all kind of used boxes, I will ask new question(s) :-).